# Can't open lib '/home/user/install/os410042/var/progress/DataDirect/Connect64_for_ODBC_71/lib/ddora27.so' : file not found

Tags: linux, oracle, odbc, unixodbc

We have an application which works with oracle. Our application servers run in the Linux Platforms, and we have database servers running on the Windows machine. We are currently testing the new Progress ODBC driver to connect the Oracle DB from Linux server. So i have installed the DATA DIRECT PROGRESS ORACLE ODBC DRIVER, when i try to connect i got the below error

[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/home/user/install/os410042/var/progress/DataDirect/Connect64_for_ODBC_71/lib/ddora27.so' : file not found

below is my ODBC.ini entry , and through isql i can able to connect to the Oracle Machine , but only my application is unable to connect.

```
        [ODBC Data Sources]
    Oracle Wire Protocol=DataDirect 7.1 Oracle Wire Protocol
    ORACLE_TEST_DSN=DataDirect 7.1 Oracle Wire Protocol

    [ODBC]
    IANAAppCodePage=4
    InstallDir=/home/user/install/os410042/var/progress/DataDirect/Connect64_for_ODBC_71
    Trace=0
    TraceFile=odbctrace.out
    TraceDll=/home/user/install/os410042/var/progress/DataDirect/Connect64_for_ODBC_71/lib/ddtrc27.so

    [ORACLE_TEST_DSN]
    Driver=/home/user/install/os410042/var/progress/DataDirect/Connect64_for_ODBC_71/lib/ddora27.so
    Description=DataDirect 7.1 Oracle Wire Protocol For Oracle
    AlternateServers=
    ApplicationUsingThreads=1
    AccountingInfo=
    Action=
    ApplicationName=
```

ldd ddora27.so also fine , it doesnt show anything not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the DataDirect setup script to set variables: Two scripts, odbc.csh and odbc.sh, are installed in the installation directory. For Korn, Bourne, and equivalent shells, execute odbc.sh. For a C shell, execute odbc.csh. After running the setup script, execute the env command to verify that the ODBCHOME/lib directory has been added to your shared library path.

[Link to related documentation](https://documentation.progress.com/output/DataDirect/DataDirectCloud/index.html#page/odbc/configuring-an-odbc-data-source-on-unix-and-linu.html).

An application restart may be required to pick up the new shared library path. Once the environment is configured, you'll be able to load the drivers.